# Volley method will not run

Tags: android, android-volley

I am having problem with this method using Volley in my Android app. From my debugging it seems like the code never runs for some reason.  I can't seem to find any solution, and I got no errors while running the app.

Could someone please help, and provide some code/solution.
Thanks in advance.

```
RequestQueue queue;

// My nav-drawer and some other code removed. That is not relevant. 

     public void registerPushToken(Context context,final String device_uuid,final String device_type, final String push_token){
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://app.Myapp.com/api/v2/pushtokens", new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("device_uuid", String.valueOf(FragmentedUser.getUniquePsuedoID()));
            params.put("device_type", "android");
            params.put("push_token",String.valueOf(Batch.Push.getLastKnownPushToken()));

            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(sr);
    queue.start();

}
```

Comment: which part of code is not running

Comment: The params put I knew for sure, but I think maybe there is something wrong with the whole method.

Comment: you never start your request queue.

Comment: Please see updated code. Its still not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I split the whole code into a new class

```
public class PushTokenRegister {

public static void registerPushToken(Context context) {
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
String url = "http://app.MYAPP.com/api/v2/pushtokens";

StringRequest strRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("onResponse", response);
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            }
        }) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("device_uuid", String.valueOf(FragmentedUser.getUniquePsuedoID()));
        params.put("device_type", "android");
        params.put("push_token",String.valueOf(Batch.Push.getLastKnownPushToken()));
        return params;
    }
};

queue.add(strRequest);
queue.start();
}
}
```

And call it from this method inside mainActivity:

```
   PushTokenRegister.registerPushToken(getBaseContext());
```